# Adding a completion handler to a func

Tags: swift

How can I add a completion handler to this func?

```
cell.buttonAction = { [unowned self] in
            let selectedIndexPath = table[indexPath.row].commentId!
            ViewComments.commentIDNew = selectedIndexPath
       
        }
```

Normally I would use this

```
 func firstTask(completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
                code....
                completion(true)
            }
```

But I don't know how to merge this.

Comment: `func` is a keyword. There is not actually a thing called a “func”.

Comment: *This func* **is** the (completion) handler. The only difference is it isn't `@escaping`. And the underscore and the parameter label of`_ success: Bool` is Swift 2 legacy syntax.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? When do you expect the completion to be called? What do you plan to do in the completion?